# how to get Linux kernel 3.18 rc4 main line to use oom_score_adj lib

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, archlinux, linux-from-scratch

Not sure if this is two question, but I wanted to start with both here in case they are related. I use a Linux PXE and grub for dos boot in various ways. I have used the same file system adding a few scripts here and there but mostly updating the kernel for new hardware. Starting with kernel 3.12.xxx and the latest 3.18 rc4 main line I am getting "oom_adj" deprecated and some wait_for_sysfs errors. My Linux skill level is somewhat basic out of ignorance mostly. I have goggled and learned a lot, so just because I use a term it does not mean I know what I am saying :-)

Background:
I started by remastering P.I.N.G from windowsdream. http://www.windowsdream.com/ping.html This is a cool ISO that will backup and restore hard drive images to a share. It's basically a big Pearl script that uses Linux commands to create shares, save partition, clear and make them back. So I started with that and made a intrd.gz file system. So I imagine a lot of my issues could be out of date lib's, my udev rules need to be updated, or my kernel make file (.config) is wrong. Also, sometimes, not always, my mouse USB will cycle though disconnects/re-connects. It seems to very from boot to boot. This boot may do it and the next boot will not. I will attache some screen shots and my .config file. BTW, P.I.N.G was based on Linux From Scratch (LFS).

Questions:
The open ended question is how to fix it?
Are the following questions related?
Is there setting in the .config to switch from oom_adj to oom_score_adj?
Is the /proc/2000 a lib issue?
Is the waiting_for_sysfs udev rules issues?
[image: Screen Shot]
For the USB disconnecting/re-connecting, I read somewhere that Intel question something about some timing and some cheaper hardware may have pushed the spec a little. I can not find it any more. I did find something in the .config about using uHCI, but I saw somewhere about xHCI. I assume it has something to do with USB 2.0 vs USB 3.0, but I am not sure. Also, is this USB 1?  [image: Screen Shot]
Any thoughts?

Looks like there are too many lines for the .config, I don't see how to attach it. If anyone wants to see it, let me know either how to post it or send it to them.

Comment: Have you tried the latest `udev`? If you use an Arch Linux system, you will need to upgrade both `core/libsystemd` and `core/systemd`. That should solve your first problem at least. You may also want to take a look at [archiso](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso).

Comment: Steve, Sorry for taking so long. I was off yesterday "at the grand-kids :-)", today has been my Monday. I have only spent about hour looking at Arch. It may be exactly what I need. I downloaded a kernel and initrd, booted it, canceled the install, so I was at prompt. Let it sit and did not see any errors. The kernel was 3.17. I need to see if I can loop mount a file system. I found this URL https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_from_Existing_Linux section Method 2: Using the LiveCD Image. I will play with it tomorrow and see if the Perl script will work with Arch tools.

Comment: Steve, Ok I have not spent more than an hour. :-) I can build a bootable ISO by the script. I am having issues with using the .img in a pxe boot environment. I am using TFTPD which looks like it only supports TFTP. Unless I am missing something archiso likes http,nfs and such. Do you have a pxelinux.0 config that boots the img that archiso makes? Here is my thread . https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190677

Comment: I have used an archiso image to PXE boot my Dell 2950 following [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PXE) on the wiki. AFAIK, you need both a TFTP and HTTP server to PXE boot the image. I use dnsmasq to take care of the networking and file transfer etc, and darkhttpd to perform the boot.

Comment: Sorry, missed your reply. The box does not have a HTTP server. Maybe I need to look at a different Linux flavor. :-(